# Service trying to proccess a request reponse using the Volley library but callback never gets called

Tags: android, android-service, android-volley

A `VolleyRequest` is not being processed properly within `Service`.

```
public class StatusService extends Service {
  private static final String TAG = StatusService.class.getSimpleName();

  @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // check the global background data setting
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (!cm.getBackgroundDataSetting()) {
      stopSelf();
      return;
    }

    RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    { // setup mRequestQueue
      // Instantiate the cache
      Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap

      // Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
      Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

      // Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
      mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

      // Start the queue
      mRequestQueue.start();
    }

    // do the actual work, in a separate thread
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://mydomain/something", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // I am sure the server side is working properly
        Log.d(TAG, "This never gets called! -> On response: " + response);
      }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error", error);
      }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
    Log.d(TAG, "This will be logged successfully");
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleIntent(intent);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
  }
}
```

The request is sent, but the provided callback action doesn't get called. When the server is off, the error callback gets called with `TimeOutError`. Is it a thread problem? If yes, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure why one would be called and not the other. However according to the documentation, even though that might be completely irrelevant to your issue, the callbacks are being called on the main thread.